# Win8.1: Safe Mode frequently breaks with empty black screen

Tags: windows-8.1, safe-mode, black-screen-of-death

I’ve had this problem for years: Every now and then, Safe Mode “breaks” and booting into it gives a blank black screen: no logon screen, no desktop icons, nothing. The mouse becomes visible when I move it and the “Safe Mode” text in the corners briefly appears, but it all vanishes when I stop moving the mouse. Otherwise, the mouse buttons, keyboard, etc. are unresponsive; the only way to exit is with the power button.

Weirdly, the issue doesn’t affect normal Windows, which works fine; it only affects Safe Mode. It occurs seemingly at random – sometimes after less than a week, sometimes after more than six months – so I can’t pinpoint what causes it.

(To clarify, I don’t use Safe Mode that often; I just check it weekly to make sure it still works for when I *do* need it, since it breaks so frequently.)

Running SFC fixes nothing; each time it says no corruption was found. The only way I know to fix it is to roll back to a previous System Restore point, or to reimage the drive from a full system backup.

I regularly update Windows and all other software. All my system’s drivers are up to date from [the manufacturer’s website](https://www.asus.com/ca-en/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-G750JZ/HelpDesk_Download/). I run DISM (`dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`) and SFC (`sfc /scannow`) weekly in an elevated command prompt, though that evidently doesn’t help prevent or fix this issue.

Right now, Safe Mode is again broken, and this time all my System Restore points are inexplicably corrupted, so the only option left is to reimage the drive, which is a pain and a last resort.

At the moment my most pressing concern is finding a way to fix Safe Mode so that it works again. Afterwards, I’d like to find what causes the problem to begin with and stop it from happening in the future.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Specs:**
Laptop model: Asus G750JZ-DB73
OS: Windows 8.1 Pro (x64)
Antivirus: Windows Defender + Spybot Search & Destroy
CPU: Intel Core i7-4700HQ
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 4600 + Nvidia GeForce GTX 880m
RAM: 32 GB Dual-Channel DDR3

Comment: Why are you running safe mode? You should only need to do this if there is a problem in normal mode that you cannot directly fix.

Comment: @DavidPostill I don’t use Safe Mode regularly; because I need it sometimes, I try booting into it every week to see if it still works, since it breaks often because of the above-mentioned issue.